# Array Repetition not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to create a randomized instance and a proper sequenced instances of objectts in an array, but it's not working correctly for some reason.
This is the code for it:

```
import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var eating_breakfast:Sprite;
var walking:Sprite;
var swimming:Sprite;
var art:Sprite;
var choices:Array = new Array ();
var i: Number = 0;

eating_breakfast = new Sprite ();
eating_breakfast.graphics.beginFill(0xE39D43);
eating_breakfast.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
eating_breakfast.graphics.endFill();
eating_breakfast.x = 50;
eating_breakfast.y = 50;


walking = new Sprite ();
walking.graphics.beginFill(0xC3266C);
walking.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
walking.graphics.endFill();
walking.x = 100;
walking.y = 100;


swimming = new Sprite ();
swimming.graphics.beginFill(0x48AFD1);
swimming.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
swimming.graphics.endFill();
swimming.x = 150;
swimming.y = 150;


art = new Sprite ();
art.graphics.beginFill(0xafdb44);
art.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
art.graphics.endFill();
art.x = 200;
art.y = 200;


choices.push ( eating_breakfast);
choices.push (walking);
choices.push (swimming);
choices.push (art);


stage.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, switchpic);
var indexcount = 0 ;
var randomize : Number ;
civilizedorder () ;
randomizedorder ();

function switchpic(d:MouseEvent){
removeChild (choices [indexcount - 1]);
removeChild (choices [randomize]);
civilizedorder ();
randomizedorder ();

}

function civilizedorder () {
    addChild (choices [indexcount]);
    choices [indexcount].x = 300;
    indexcount++;
    trace (indexcount);
}
trace ("The number of choices in the choice array is " + choices.length);

function randomizedorder (){
randomize  = Math.floor( Math.random () * choices.length);
trace ("the random number is" + randomize);
addChild (choices [randomize]);

}
```

Please Can somebody explain why this is happening.. according to my analysis it seems like this happens when indexcount == randomize.. how do I fix this?

Comment: You are going to have to explain what should happen, because it's not clear.

Comment: oh my apologies.. Well I have one list and I am trying to add the objects from that list to stage.. but I need 2 instances one that is randomly generated and one that is generated as in the sequence it was inserted as.. they are both part of the same list

Comment: are you saying you want a copy of each ? I'm still not understanding what you want.

Comment: ok so I have one array. I have four objects inserted in that array. I need to add 2 objects ata a time from that array to the screen. There are 2 methods I need to apply in order to add these objects to screen.. one is by random generation. and one is by adding them in a sequence they were originally put in. so each time I click there should be a randomly generated object from taht list and there needs to be the properly sequenced object to screen. Is it more clear?

Comment: yes, except what happens if the random index and the ordered index are the same ? they can't appear in two different places at the same time, as each element in your array is just one display object.

Comment: right.. so is there any wya to fix that? :D

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a couple of problems. 1 you're never resetting your indexcount number which is causing it to try to access a value out side the length of your choices array length (ie you're allowing indexcount to be greater than choices.length).
You also correctly surmised if you tried to add art twice, you only have 1 instance on the stage. However you're not checking to see if it exists or should exist when you go to remove the sprites.

```
eating_breakfast = new Sprite ();
eating_breakfast.name = "eating_breakfast";
eating_breakfast.graphics.beginFill(0xE39D43);
eating_breakfast.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
eating_breakfast.graphics.endFill();
eating_breakfast.x = 50;
eating_breakfast.y = 50;


walking = new Sprite ();
walking.name = "walking";
walking.graphics.beginFill(0xC3266C);
walking.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
walking.graphics.endFill();
walking.x = 100;
walking.y = 100;


swimming = new Sprite ();
swimming.name = "swimming";
swimming.graphics.beginFill(0x48AFD1);
swimming.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
swimming.graphics.endFill();
swimming.x = 150;
swimming.y = 150;


art = new Sprite ();
art.name = "art";
art.graphics.beginFill(0xafdb44);
art.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
art.graphics.endFill();
art.x = 200;
art.y = 200;


choices.push(eating_breakfast);
choices.push(walking);
choices.push(swimming);
choices.push(art);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, switchpic);
var indexcount = -1;
var randomize:Number;
civilizedorder();
randomizedorder();

function switchpic(d:MouseEvent) {
    removeChild(choices[indexcount]);
    if(choices[indexcount].name != choices[randomize].name){
        removeChild(choices[randomize]);
    }
    civilizedorder();
    randomizedorder();
}    

function civilizedorder() {
    indexcount++;
    if(indexcount == choices.length-1){
        indexcount = 0;
    }
    trace("adding " + choices[indexcount].name);
    addChild(choices[indexcount]);
    choices[indexcount].x = 300;
}
trace("The number of choices in the choice array is " + choices.length);

function randomizedorder() {
    randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
    trace("adding " + choices[randomize].name);
    addChild(choices[randomize]);

}
```

Sorry, I also added .name to the sprites to make it a little easier to see what's going on.

Comment: oh can u please tell me how to check if the sprite that is currently in index shouldn't be picked by the randomized.. how can I do that? or yes I am aware of indexcount problem I forgot to mention it.. but I was just trying to fix the randomize problem first

Comment: try the above, sorry I'm new to this site and am still trying to figure out the nice way of adding code :/

Comment: hah thx a lot.. I sort of meant it differently btu i figured it out from your example. Thx very much :D

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is either wrap your creation of the instances in a class or function.

```
public var choices:Array;

function Main()
{
    choices = [eatingBreakfast, walking];

    var randomIndex:int = Math.random() * choices.length;
    var choice:Function = choices[randomIndex] as Function;
    var yourSprite:Sprite = choice();

}



function eatingBreakfast():Sprite
{
    var instance:Sprite =  new Sprite;
    instance.graphics.beginFill(0xE39D43);
    instance.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
    instance.graphics.endFill();
    instance.x = 50;
    instance.y = 50;
    return instance;
}


function walking():Sprite
{
    var instance:Sprite =  new Sprite;
    instance.graphics.beginFill(0xE39D43);
    instance.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
    instance.graphics.endFill();
    instance.x = 50;
    instance.y = 50;
    return instance;
}
```

This example was using functions that return an `Sprite` instance, but I'd recommend using a class per type or a function that returns an instance based on some kind of identifier.